# No service for type X has been registered, but service registration looks ok?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have some very simple code in Startup.cs in a ASP.NET Core 2.0 web project:

```
public async void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    await CreateContainer();

    services.AddSingleton<Infrastructure.Logging.Contracts.ILogger, Infrastructure.Logging.Standard.Logger>();
}

private async Task CreateContainer()
{
    string connectionString = Configuration["TestConnectionString"];
    var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("logs");
    await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
}
```

In my home page view, I have:

```
@using Infrastructure.Logging.Contracts
@inject ILogger logger
```

The problem is that the application crashes (when running the code in the view) with:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Infrastructure.Logging.Contracts.ILogger' has been registered.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
```

All the code in Startup.cs runs successful with no exceptions.

But, if I change the ConfigureServices method by moving a single line of code like this:

```
public async void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddSingleton<Infrastructure.Logging.Contracts.ILogger, Infrastructure.Logging.Standard.Logger>();

    await CreateContainer();
}
```

Everything now runs successfully with no error messages.

How can the call to the CreateContainer method cause an error when trying to inject the registered class? There should be no relationship whatsoever between these operations.

Note that the call to register the service runs successful in any case and in the debugger I can see the entry for the registered service by examining the services object. There are no exceptions, which could alter the flow of execution somehow. I have stepped through in the debugger and checked everything.

Comment: are you registering the service by name? "logs?"

Comment: Most likely your `CreateContainer` operation takes some time to run. `ConfigureServices` method exits immediately after starting your `CreateContainer` operation and framework goes to the next things to do. One of those things is  displaying your view. So when view is about to be shown - your service might not be registered because CreateContainer is still running. Easiest way to check it is logging (can be just `Console.Write`) after `await CreateContainer` and see if that happens before or after your exception. If after (doesn't happen at all) - that means this assumption is correct.

Comment: The code to register the service is shown in the code snippet.

Comment: The view for the home page does not get invoked until the ConfigureServices method has been exited. I have a breakpoint at the end and no browser window is showed until I continue execution after ConfigureServices are completely executed. I also experience exactly the same issue on browser refresh long after startup of the application.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The problem is caused by calling await on an async method inside the ConfigureServices method. I tried to replace this line of code:

```
await CreateContainer();
```

with:

```
await Task.Delay(200);
```

and the problem still reproduced.

This is the fixed version of the ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    CreateContainer().Wait();

    services.AddSingleton<Infrastructure.Logging.Contracts.ILogger, Infrastructure.Logging.Standard.Logger>();
}
```

I'm not exactly sure why this caused a problem, but it must have caused some sort of synchronization issues in the framework code.

Comment: You start the `async` operation and do not wait for it, it's not the framework. You also should use the `Wait()`, use `await`. Moreover, you really shouldn't do the `ConfigureServices` async - it's against the conventions, it doesn't meant to be async at all

Comment: Which async operation did I start and did not wait for it?