# How to use OData in Asp.net Core Web API without Entity Model?

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using OData in Asp.net Core web API. I am new to OData.

I used the Odata like this:

**Controller**

```
 [EnableQuery]
 public async Task<ActionResult> ListAsync([FromODataUri]ODataQueryOptions<Orders> opts)
 {
   .........
 }`
```

**Model**

```
 public List<Orders> GetList(ODataQueryOptions<Orders> opts)
 {
     if (order.Count == 0) 
        BindDataSource(); 
     var results = order.AsQueryable(); 
     var count = results.Count(); 
     if (opts.OrderBy != null) 
        results = opts.OrderBy.ApplyTo(results); 
     if (opts.Filter != null) 
     { 
        if (opts.Filter.RawValue.Contains("substring")) 
        { 
            string key = opts.Filter.RawValue.Split(new string[] { "'" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]; 
            results = results.Where(fil => fil.CustomerID.Contains(key) || fil.EmployeeID.ToString().Contains(key) || fil.Freight.ToString().Contains(key) || fil.OrderID.ToString().Contains(key) || fil.ShipCity.Contains(key) || fil.OrderDate.ToString().Contains(key)); 
        } 
        else 
            results = opts.Filter.ApplyTo(results, new ODataQuerySettings()).Cast<Orders>(); 
        }
     }
     if (opts.InlineCount != null) 
        count = results.Count(); 
     if (opts.Skip != null) 
        results = opts.Skip.ApplyTo(results, new ODataQuerySettings()); 
     if (opts.Top != null) 
        results = opts.Top.ApplyTo(results, new ODataQuerySettings());
 }
```

**Note**

I no need to create EDM for using OData.

https://damienbod.com/2018/10/12/odata-with-asp-net-core/

Here, it is integrated with entity framework. But I no need to integrate. I need to use it's attribute only.

How to use it?

When I am running the API, I am getting an error like

```
InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNet.OData.ODataOptions' has been registered.
```

**Note**

I need to use OData in web API without EDM.

Comment: What specific areas are you struggling with? You can absolutely do this without EF but your example is only partial so it's hard to see where you are having trouble. Can you successfully debug into the call to GetList()?

Comment: Also, you have not implemented the filter option, this should be before the `if (opts.InlineCount…`

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I am getting an error when running the API. I added the error in the description.

Comment: I haven't experienced issues like this, but again you have only posted some of the code, this initially looks like a general web api issue, have you had a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/46890691/1690217